# Formula for unique orderings of N items from k bins sorted contiguously.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for a formula that will tell me how many unique orderings I can get if I pick out $N$ items from $k$ bins that those items are divided into in continuous segments. For example, for $N=4$ and $k=2$, the $2$ bins are: $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$. Each time I pick an item from the front of each bin (without replacement). So this gives me $6$ unique total orderings $\{0,2,1,3\}, \{2,0,1,3\}, \{0,2,1,3\}, \{0,2,3,1\}, \{2,0,3,1\}, \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $\{2,3,0,1\}$. Similarly for $N=8$ and $k=2$, the bins would be $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5,6,7\}$. With $k=1$, I should only get one single order and with $k=N$, I should get $N!$ orders.

I'm looking for a formula I can use to calculate the number of possible permutations for any given $N$ and $k$. I've used powers of $2$ here but I would like the formula to work with any value such as $N=7, k=4$ say. $k$ will only ever be a power of $2$.

Comment: **Hint**  Let the first bin be called $A$ and the second bin be called $B$.  Compare the orderings you listed $\{0,2,1,3\},\{2,0,1,3\},\{0,2,3,1\},\dots$ with the related sequences $ABAB,BAAB,ABBA,\dots$ where we don't bother writing *which* number from the respective bin it was... just the letter for the bin itself.  (*[additional hint/answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)*)

Comment: @JMoravitz so in this case the ordering does matter for me. so those would be distinct even if the sequence is ABAB for two of them. Sorry, my background in combinatorics is rather poor and I just need this formula for a paper I'm writing and a i can't get at a the formula.

Comment: So when $N=7$ and $k=3$, two of the bins have $2$ items and the third has $3$?  What is the general rule?

Comment: @saulspatz sorry, that was a mistake. k should only ever be a power of 2. so i changed it to N=7 and k=4. In this case however, each bin would have ⌈7/4⌉ =  2 items with just the last bin have 1.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan the point is that you *won't* have the sequence be ABAB *for two of them*, you would only ever have the sequence be ABAB for one of them.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you. I get what you mean now. Once I saw the formula and I plugged in some numbers it made sense. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JMoravitz indicated in his comment, all that matters is the sequence in which you pick the bins.  The first time you pick the bin, you get the fits number in it.  The second time you get the second number, and so on.

In your first example, the sequence $1122$ would mean pick the first bin twice, then then second bin twice, so it would result in the sequence $0123$.  Similarly, $1221$ would give the sequence $0231$.

If there are $q$ bins with $a$ items each and $r$ bins with $b$ items each, where $aq+br=N$, then the number of possible sequences is $$\frac {N!}{(a!)^q(b!)^r}$$

In the example you gave of $7$ items in $4$ bins, $3$ of the  bins have $2$ items and $1$ bin has one item, so the number of sequences is $$\frac{7!}{(2!)^3(1!)^1}=630$$